# Regular Expression to remove underscore and string

Tags: php, regex

I need to use PHP regex to remove '_normal' from the end of this url.

http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3707137637/8b020cf4023476238704a9fc40cdf445**_normal**.jpeg

so that it becomes

http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3707137637/8b020cf4023476238704a9fc40cdf445.jpeg.

I tried

```
$prof_img = preg_replace('_normal', '', $prof_img);
```

but the underscore seems to be throwing things off.

Comment: Did you enable `error_reporting` yet?

Answer (score 7):

As others have stated, `str_replace` is probably the best option for this simple example.

The problem with your specific code is that your regex string is undelimited, you need to this instead:

```
$prof_img = preg_replace('/_normal/', '', $prof_img);
```

See [PCRE regex syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) for a reference.

The underscore is treated as a normal character in PCRE and isn't throwing things off.

If you require that only `_normal` at the end of the filename is matched, you can use:

```
$prof_img = preg_replace('/_normal(\.[^\.]+)$/', '$1', $prof_img);
```

See [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for more information on how this works.

Comment: This will match *any* `_normal` in the url; maybe that's not a problem, but just fyi.

Answer (score 3):

Try using str_replace; it's much more efficient than regex for something like this.

However, if you want to use regular expressions, you need a delimiter:

`preg_replace('|_normal|','', $url);`

Comment: Can you explain what your regular expression is doing..?

Comment: It's replacing the literal string "_normal" with an empty string. The pipes `|` are delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

`str_replace` should work.

```
$prof_img = str_replace('_normal', '', $prof_img);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to add delimiters around your regex.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is
>   enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric,
>   non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and
>   tildes (~). The following are all examples of valid delimited
>   patterns.

```
$prof_img = preg_replace('/_normal/', '', $prof_img);

$prof_img = preg_replace('#_normal#', '', $prof_img);

$prof_img = preg_replace('~_normal~', '', $prof_img);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use decompose the URL first, perform the replacement and stick them back together, i.e.

```
$url = 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3707137637/8b020cf4023476238704a9fc40cdf445_normal.jpeg';

$parts = pathinfo($url);
// transform
$url = sprintf('%s%s.%s', 
     $parts['dirname'],
     preg_replace('/_normal$/', '', $parts['filename']),
     $parts['extension']
);
```

You might note two differences between your expression and mine:

1. Yours wasn't delimited.
2. Mine is anchored, i.e. it only removes `_normal` if it occurs at the *end* of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Using non-capturing groups, you can also try like this:

```
$prof_img = preg_replace('/(.+)(?:_normal)(.+)/', '$1$2', $prof_img);
```

It will keep the required part as a match.